# How to test javascript hide/show behaviors on authenticated pages?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, capybara, jasmine

**Context:** When a user is logged and consulting his own profile, he can click on his avatar, this click displays a Dropdown menu with an option 'Upload avatar'. When the user clicks on this option, it opens a modal with a form for uploading a new image for the avatar.
I am using twitter bootstrap to handle the dropdown (and the modal).

Of course, I want to test this. But I don't know how.

Let's concentrate on the dropdown feature, as the modal tests will probably almost identical :

At first I was thinking of using capybara, but there is no way to check if an element is visible through its CSS property `display: none` or `display: block`. 
I read that some people advices to check for a class like `hidden` through capybara. But in this case, as I am using Twitter Bootstrap, there is only a `dropdown` for instance.

And I don't want to modify bootstrap behavior just to be able to test it, it would be a smell.

Here is a sample of my rspec suite :

```
describe 'should display a dropdown menu' do
   let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
   before do
     sign_in_as user
     # I have routes just like that: /1/firstname-lastname
     visit(profile_path(id: user.id, first: user.first_name.downcase, last: user.last_name.downcase))

     click_link 'avatar-dropdown'
   end
   it { should have_css('.dropdown-menu', visible: true) }
   describe 'with an upload link' do [...] end
end
```

The HTML looks like :

```
<div class="dropdown" id="avatar-menu">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="avatar-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#avatar-menu">
    <%= @user.avatar %>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="upload-avatar" href="#">Upload an image</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- #upload-menu -->
```

Of course, it is not working with `visible: true`, as the `display: none` is set by twitter bootstrap's CSS.

Then, I thought about testing this behavior with Jasmine (A good occasion to dive in), but if I do so, how should I register a user ?
I don't know if it shares the test database, but I don't think I can use factory girl to generate new users in Jasmine, can I ?
I don't even know if visiting the register page in Jasmine (if it is even possible ?) and submitting the form would do the trick. Same with the authentication.

How can I test those behaviors ? Should I use capybara (Is there a trick ?) or Jasmine (What is the way to go, then ?)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have managed to get things work with capybara. I am not sure it would work for each and every other case, but in my case it worked :

We need to activate [Selenium](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/) for Capybara by passing `js: true` to either `describe` or `it`

```
describe 'should display a dropdown menu', js: true do
   let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
   before do
     sign_in_as user
     # I have routes just like that: /1/firstname-lastname
     visit(profile_path(id: user.id, first: user.first_name.downcase, last: user.last_name.downcase))

     click_link 'avatar-dropdown'
   end
   it { should have_css('.dropdown-menu', visible: true) }
   describe 'with an upload link' do [...] end
end
```

This way, capybara seem to really check if the attribute is visible or not.
It also launch Firefox every time I run the tests, which can be pretty painful.

Answer (score 1):

> At first I was thinking of using capybara, but there is no way to
>   check if an element is visible through its CSS property display: none
>   or display: block

Can you not do something like:

```
page.has_xpath?("/xpath/here[contains(@style, 'display: block')]")
```

where 'display: none' would replace 'display: block' when it is invisible.